# How to call the teamname/_text and display it in html. the / is messing it up

Tags: html, css, json

{
offset: 0,
results: [
{
teamname_link/_text: "BAL",
teamname_link: "http://www.usatoday.com/sports/mlb/orioles/",
},

Answer (score 0):

if it's javascript you can use the array notation.

```
var result = '{ offset: 0, results: [ { teamname_link/_text: "BAL", teamname_link: "http://www.usatoday.com/sports/mlb/orioles/" ]}';
console.log(result.results[0]['teamname_link/_text']);
```

Comment: Thanks Man! it worked... so my question is why does it work when i write {{results[0]['teamname_link/_text']}} but when i write {{results[0].teamname_link/_text}} it breaks

Comment: because of the special characters in the propety name. in this case it's the slash.